# When i try to deploy heroku i got this error ! [remote rejected] farzana -> main (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: heroku, git-push

I build a group project. When I try to deploy my project in heroku I got this error several time
do you have any idea about heroku deployment  !
[remote rejected] farzana -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/guarded-taiga-13015.git'
How can I fix this error?

Comment: That seems to be git related issue, some of your git hooks fail when you're pushing. Try running git pull command first

Comment: I tried to do this bro. but it's not working still now. do you have any other solution?

Comment: The error message you've shared is the least helpful part. What does it say above that? Please [edit] your question and include all relevant errors.

Comment: i edited my post with an image. please check this error.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: In any case, the error message very clearly says what the problem is and how to fix it. Please always read error messages as they tend to include helpful information. If you can't understand them yourself, please always include them when asking questions.

Comment: If anyone faces this problem please run only one package manager. yarn or npm. and delete another manager. then push in Netlify it will be worded.